# Slow boot, long kernel load time, due to wrong resume device

Tags: boot, kernel

For some time, my boot process is taking too long (almost 1 min.).

```
systemd-analyze time
```

shows that kernel is taking 35.765s

Looking at `dmesg`, it seems that the problem is with mounting file systems:

```
...
[    2.186084]  sdb: sdb1 sdb9
[    2.186919] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] supports TCG Opal
[    2.186922] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[    2.499795] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    2.844320] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[   35.670493] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   35.782128] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[   35.803610] systemd[1]: systemd 237 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
...
```

My `/etc/fstab` looks like this:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=3996-2381  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
#/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

How can I troubleshoot this ?

EDIT: looking closely at the boot messages (after removing the quiet option in grub), I spotted this suspicious line:

```
gave up waiting for suspend/resume device
```

I think my swap is encrypted, and I also think the UUID in `/etc/initramfs/conf.d/resume` does not correspond to any device.

Should I disable resume/suspend? and how to do that?

Comment: The problem is actually at
```
    Begin: Running /scripts/local-premount
```
It is displayed during the boot (if you disable quiet). Due to some reason this premount script is taking a 30 seconds or so.

Comment: This question/answer is valuable because it helps solve a bug in Lubuntu Bionic, so please help reopen it :-)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution, thanks to Sudhanshu's comment.

The problem was due to my swap being encrypted. So the `local-premount` script in initramfs was waiting for a swap device that was not available, until it timed out. The relevant message was `gave up waiting for suspend/resume device`.

To disable this (as resuming from swap is not possible with an encrypted swap, and I don't use hibernation anyway), I modified this file: `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`.

In this file, a line with

```
RESUME=none
```

(instead of the UUID that was here) will disable waiting for a resume device.

Run

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

to apply the changes.

System now boots normally.

Comment: I think you are affected by [Bug #1763611, Lubuntu bionic boots slower than the other Ubuntu flavours with some SSDs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lubuntu-meta/+bug/1763611). And you have shown how to squash the bug :-)

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for the fix. It had me pulling my hair out!

Comment: Had the problem since a long time caused by zram (no swap partition). I just fixed it, thanks !

Comment: Thanks it worked!

Comment: Weird thing, commenting the line out wasn't fixing it. I wonder how you found out what you had to put there. Thanx, damn thing was driving me nuts :-D

Comment: @DimiDak I looked at the boot messages in dmesg after disabling quiet mode in grub... It was a bit of a guess work...

Answer (score 7):

I also saw this in Linux Mint (based on Ubuntu), and spent some time working out what was going wrong.

This happens if your system is installed on LVM and is using an LVM volume as the swap disk.

There is a long-standing, recurring bug where the resume file incorrectly has a UUID (which is invalid for LVM) instead of the device path that it should have.
See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1768230

You can fix it by editing the `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` file and replacing the UUID with the device path of the swap drive.
The following command snippet will do this for you, using the first swap drive found and reported by blkid:

```
sudo bash -c 'mv /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume /tmp/resume.bak; echo RESUME=$(blkid | \grep -i swap | head -n 1 | cut -d : -f 1) > /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume'
```

The fixed resume file should look something like this:
`RESUME=/dev/mapper/mint--vg-swap_1`

Comment: This script won't work for everyone (like me). Please include what the actual `resume` file contents will look like afterwards.

Comment: The resume file should look something like this: `RESUME=/dev/mapper/mint--vg-swap_1`

Comment: Thank you, +1 

Comment: I think there is a typo: `grep -i`instead of `grep -I`

the correct line likely to be:
 
`sudo bash -c 'mv /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume /tmp/resume.bak; echo RESUME=$(blkid | \grep -i swap | head -n 1 | cut -d : -f 1) > /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume'`

Answer (score 3):

None of those solutions above or elsewhere worked out for me but I have found a solution which reduces my boot time to 40 seconds from 2 minutes and 10 seconds.

I used to create and remove swap partitions and somehow these logs stayed in etc/fstab file. So my system was trying to mount those previously created swap partitions which no longer exists. So please let me explain what I did step by step.

1. I ran this command `sudo blkid | grep swap` to find out my swap partitions. There was two but one does not actually exist (it does not refer to any of my partitions).
2. So I went to edit /etc/fstab file by typing `sudo gedit /etc/fstab`
3. Then I realized there are so many swap files which I had deleted but somehow resumed existing in this file. So I referred to step 1 and *deleted partitions which no longer exist*.

Please see two before & after /etc/fstab file screenshots. After this cleanout everything's working as normal.

This is unedited /etc/fstab file [unedited /etc/fstab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIu9F.png)

and here after wiping out non-existing swap partitions [clean /etc/fstab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xflj.png)

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me, all I had to do open fstab to see the line that referred to a swap file on a partition that had been deleted and whose reference I'd also deleted in grub. I'd recommend doing that first - check fstab and look for references to swap file you know don't exist.

Answer (score 3):

I got this problem after installing 2 different linux distros.
Somehow, on one distro, the swap partition got another UUID assigned to it then expected.
My solution was  to:
First, run `sudo blkid` to get the right UUID for the swap partition.
Copy the UUID of the swap.
Paste it in `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` so you get `RESUME=_the_correct_UUID_`.
Now run `sudo update-initramfs -u` to apply this change.

Next, check /etc/fstab, and change the UUID of the swap partition there also if necessary. (I had to)

Comment: This helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, adding configuration files in `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/` (with `RESUME=none` etc.) as said in the other answers didn't work for me. Ubuntu continues to report at boot time:

> gave up waiting for suspend/resume device

The solution that worked for me is to change `grub` configuration at `/etc/default/grub` and change the line from something like the following:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=7f6bbc71-07d2-46db-946c-03e47368706c"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash noresume"
```

then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```