# 18.04 delayed boot - which device?

Tags: boot

I don't know how to read `systemd-analyze` well enough to understand how to fix my own delayed boot problem. Ubuntu 17.10 booted very quickly for me, and I understand that 18.04 is actually faster once configured correctly.

Can you help **identify the delaying process(es) and any solutions**?

time

```
Startup finished in 4.282s (firmware) + 4.215s (loader) + 35.104s (kernel) + 34.337s (userspace) = 1min 17.940s
graphical.target reached after 34.328s in userspace
```

critical-chain

```
graphical.target @34.328s
└─multi-user.target @34.328s
  └─docker.service @33.161s +1.166s
    └─network-online.target @33.156s
      └─network.target @3.132s
        └─NetworkManager.service @2.551s +575ms
          └─dbus.service @2.472s
            └─basic.target @2.385s
              └─sockets.target @2.385s
                └─docker.socket @2.383s +970us
                  └─sysinit.target @2.374s
                    └─systemd-timesyncd.service @2.054s +319ms
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @1.980s +53ms
                        └─local-fs.target @1.978s
                          └─run-snapd-ns-bluez.mnt.mount @33.434s
                            └─run-snapd-ns.mount @33.193s
                              └─swap.target @1.864s
                                └─dev-mapper-cryptswap1.swap @1.812s +9ms
                                  └─dev-mapper-cryptswap1.device @1.812s
```

blame

```
     30.022s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      4.302s apt-daily-upgrade.service
      1.664s keyboard-setup.service
      1.615s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      1.166s docker.service
      1.102s dev-nvme0n1p5.device
       777ms fwupd.service
       729ms networkd-dispatcher.service
       688ms systemd-logind.service
       575ms NetworkManager.service
       521ms gpu-manager.service
       516ms udisks2.service
       516ms systemd-cryptsetup@cryptswap1.service
       496ms snap-pycharm\x2dprofessional-66.mount
       453ms snap-bluez-129.mount
       446ms ModemManager.service
       434ms snap-pycharm\x2dprofessional-64.mount
       413ms snap-intellij\x2didea\x2dultimate-47.mount
       410ms snap-intellij\x2didea\x2dultimate-44.mount
       395ms accounts-daemon.service
       350ms nbfc.service
       349ms grub-common.service
       340ms unbound.service
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
systemctl stop NetworkManager-wait-online.service
systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

This service does not come from out-of-box Ubuntu 18.04
I tcan be installed as dependence, im told that Steam installs it

Comment: Odd. I don't have Steam! I disabled and rebooted. `Startup finished in 4.711s (firmware) + 3.238s (loader) + 35.111s (kernel) + 9.057s (userspace) = 52.118s` Same results.

Comment: `apt-daily-upgrade.service` can be disabled too

Comment: This fixed the issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013830/slow-boot-long-kernel-load-time-due-to-wrong-resume-device. However, I am having strange graphical switches between boot, login screen, and logged in desktop. Working on drivers now.

Comment: please check 'fixed' flag