# Very slow boot on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, performance

I recently switched from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 18.04 - the boot time increased significantly. I don't know squat about Linux, found some commands online and this is their result:

```
     30.014s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      3.209s apt-daily-upgrade.service

Startup finished in 3.997s (firmware) + 11.073s (loader) + 34.461s (kernel) + 31.580s (userspace) = 1min 21.113s
graphical.target reached after 31.574s in userspace
```

Also from command dmesg:

```
[    3.196338] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
[   34.353573] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)

[   37.359921] wlp3s0: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by 10:62:d0:1a:6a:5b
[   40.492024] usb 1-1.1: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[   40.966771] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   40.966772] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   40.966775] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   45.898314] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=13d3, idProduct=3362
[   45.898319] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   45.898322] usb 1-1.1: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[   45.898325] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: Atheros Communications
[   45.898328] usb 1-1.1: SerialNumber: Alaska Day 2006
[   47.310992] wlp3s0: deauthenticating from 10:62:d0:1a:6a:5b by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[   48.478143] wlp3s0: authenticate with 10:62:d0:1a:6a:5b
[   48.497623] wlp3s0: send auth to 10:62:d0:1a:6a:5b (try 1/3)
[   48.531905] wlp3s0: authenticated
[   48.535980] wlp3s0: associate with 10:62:d0:1a:6a:5b (try 1/3)
[   48.541475] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 10:62:d0:1a:6a:5b (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=1)
[   48.541590] wlp3s0: associated
[   48.541709] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8114
[   48.541711] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[   48.541712] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[   48.541714] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[   48.541715] ath: Country alpha2 being used: DE
[   48.541716] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[   48.541718] ath: regdomain 0x8114 dynamically updated by country IE
[   48.579891] wlp3s0: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by 10:62:d0:1a:6a:5b
[   52.070060] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   52.070076] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   52.070080] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   53.093985] rfkill: input handler disabled
[   58.542229] wlp3s0: deauthenticating from 10:62:d0:1a:6a:5b by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[   63.018217] wlp3s0: authenticate with 10:62:d0:1a:6a:5b
[   63.032644] wlp3s0: send auth to 10:62:d0:1a:6a:5b (try 1/3)
[   63.034615] wlp3s0: authenticated
[   63.039967] wlp3s0: associate with 10:62:d0:1a:6a:5b (try 1/3)
[   63.045433] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from 10:62:d0:1a:6a:5b (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=1)
[   63.045543] wlp3s0: associated
[   63.045628] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8114
[   63.045629] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[   63.045639] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[   63.045640] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[   63.045641] ath: Country alpha2 being used: DE
[   63.045642] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[   63.045643] ath: regdomain 0x8114 dynamically updated by country IE
[   63.088419] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
[   63.132007] wlp3s0: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by 10:62:d0:1a:6a:5b
```

This looks to me like the parts slowing down. What is the cause of this?

EDIT: As pointed in the comment, I did what the accepted answer here suggests: [fix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013830/slow-boot-long-kernel-load-time-due-to-wrong-resume-device)

Now some warning message appears when booting, I'll try to disable quiet boot to see it.

Comment: I did what was in the accepted answer here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013830/slow-boot-long-kernel-load-time-due-to-wrong-resume-device - it shortened the time by about half, but now some warning is flashing when system boots. I'll try to see what's the message.

Answer (score 0):

Have you formatted dm-0 (LVM?) with mke2fs? Maybe [this](https://superuser.com/questions/855547/mounted-filesystem-without-journal-opts-null-while-mounting-ext4-fs) could be useful for you.