# Slow boot time (Xubuntu 18.04)

Tags: boot

I'm running Xubuntu 18.04 as a new install (and only OS) on a Dell Latitude 3189 with an SSD. The computer takes consistently 60-65 seconds between the Dell splash screen and the Xubuntu log-in screen. All of that time is spent with a black screen.

After doing some searching online, I updated the /etc/fstab file with the correct UUIDs but that did not improve the boot time.

I have run the "systemd-analyze blame" command and its output is here: https://pastebin.com/KNqah8BC. Adding the times on that list comes out to 14.872 seconds, which would be a better start-up time; I don't know where the discrepancy is coming from.

I have also run the "dmesg" command and its output is here: https://pastebin.com/3J3p0Kma. This seems to show a few slowdowns:

```
[    4.828692] [drm] RC6 on
[   35.319629] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

...

```
[   38.162979] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp1s0: link is not ready
[   45.938821] wlp1s0: authenticate with ac:84:c6:a3:d0:a2
```

...

```
[   47.304167] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   93.404225] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
```

I'm not sure how to address those. Any ideas on how I can fix things? I'm completely new to Linux, so basic answers (and explanations of what I'm doing) would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Following another [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013830/slow-boot-long-kernel-load-time-due-to-wrong-resume-device) I found the solution which works in my case:

- Modified this file: `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`.

  In this file, a line with

  ```
  RESUME=none
  ```

  (instead of the UUID that was here) will disable waiting for a resume device.
- Run

  ```
  sudo update-initramfs -u
  ```

  to apply the changes.