# Error on boot: "failed to connect to lvmetad" after 18.04 install

Tags: boot, 18.04, lvm

I have been using Ubuntu 16.04 for a couple of years now, and recently did an upgrade to 18.04. This was not a fresh installation, but rather an upgrade as per instructions, from 16.04 to 18.04. Everything went to plan, except that now whenever my computer boots up, it takes an eternity to boot, and briefly flashes up the following error:

```
failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning
Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: clean, 550775/30154752 files, 23702732/120600576 blocks
```

If I wait long enough, then the computer boots just fine after this. Looking online I see that LVM is a feature which works a bit like a virtual RAID system, compiling multiple drives into one virtual drive/partition/s etc. I have however never used this.

Is LVM something mandated by Ubuntu 18.04? Do I have to use it? If not, how do I get rid of it?

My computer never had an issue before and always booted very quickly. I only have a single SSD drive in my machine, so LVM would be superfluous to requirements for me.

Thanks for the help guys!

Subsequent research has lead me to believe this is a known bug. I have used the suggestion here (to modify GRUB such that it does not resume)

[How to diagnose/fix very slow boot on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030867/how-to-diagnose-fix-very-slow-boot-on-ubuntu-18-04/1031667#1031667)

Furthermore I also used this link to modify `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` and disable resuming as explained in [Slow boot, long kernel load time, due to wrong resume device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013830/slow-boot-long-kernel-load-time-due-to-wrong-resume-device)

Apparently this affects a machine's ability to resume from hibernation too, so not too good a workaround if you wish to retain that feature (which I do not).

With that done the boot time has been reduced by about 20 seconds, however I still get the original message flashing up, which means it's still looking for some virtual volume or swap file that does not exist (I don't use one, who would!).

Hopefully this helps somebody, or at least until the bug is fixed at some point.

FYI - Bug report can be found [here on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1768230)