# lvmetad and ubuntu-vg boot errors

Tags: boot, lvm

My laptop was initially configured with an encrypted hard drive with 18.10. After upgrading to 19.04 I noticed the following errors during bootup:

```
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
Volume group "ubuntu-vg" not found
Cannot process volume group ubuntu.vg
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.
Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: clean, 789506/120987648 files etc etc.
```

Then I subsequently get a successful bootup.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Slow boot, long kernel load time, due to wrong resume device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013830/slow-boot-long-kernel-load-time-due-to-wrong-resume-device)