# 18.04 - More than 2 mins boot on SSD

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, ssd, dmesg

I've Ubuntu 18.04 installed on Dell Latitude E6320 (on Kingstone SSD), It used to boot in about 14 - 18 sec, but about three days ago the system started to take a lot of time to boot and in general slow performance.

`systemd-analyze` outputs

```
Startup finished in 7.782s (kernel) + 42.572s (userspace) = 50.354s
graphical.target reached after 42.544s in userspace
```

(I'm on EFI).

The actual boot time is about 2 min from grub screen until the Plymouth screen and then another 30s until the login screen shows up.

#### What caused the problem?

I did a usual software update and it included a kernel upgrade to **5.0.0-36-generic**. restarted the system and the problem started.

#### What I've tried.

- Tried to boot with the previous kernel (5.0.0.32) but nothing happened
  (grub hangs at `loading initial ramdisk` then shows Plymouth screen)
- Removed swap 'file' and updated `fstab` to not include it
- Added `noresume` option to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` `etc/default/grub/`
- Tried the solution listed here ([Slow boot, long kernel load time, due to wrong resume device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013830/slow-boot-long-kernel-load-time-due-to-wrong-resume-device))
  Actually I didn't have `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` file so i created one.

#### System specification

- Dell Latitude E6320 with the latest BIOS update.
- Dual-booting Ubuntu 18.04 on SSD, and Windows 10 on completely separate HDD. both using EFI (Tried to boot with the HDD removed, nothing.)

It's not the first time I face this problem. I was using Kubuntu and the same problem happened but with 8 min boot time so I did a clean EFI install of Ubuntu (about a month ago) and achieved 14sec boot time.

I've noticed performance drop especially when it comes to reading or writing from the SSD. Even typing `clare` or any wrong command in the terminal takes a bit of time to be recognized as an unknown command.

---

#### Additional troubleshooting

The output of `dmesg -k` can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/AbdulhamidZoubi/b37ec0b971e262ae9cdca48377c2ac6f).

### Update 1

`systemd-analye blame` [output](https://gist.github.com/AbdulhamidZoubi/e9051d5d7ba274c453b803dcf44af237)

`systemd-analyze critical-chain`
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydJBU.png)

Comment: Please edit/add the output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain` and `systemd-analyze blame` - First suggestion: clear the journal log with `sudo journalctl --rotate; journalctl --vacuum-time=1s`

Comment: Thank you or your quick response, I edited the question.. I tried the command you mention **with** sudo privileges but it outputs `Failed to delete archived journal /var/log/journal/.... .journal: Permission denied  `

Comment: Yep, sorry : `sudo journalctl --rotate; sudo journalctl --vacuum-time=1s`

Comment: (I forgot the second command's `sudo` sorry). executed the command successfully and about 2.1GB of logs were freed. the problem isn't solved, unfortunately.

Comment: please paste the full output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain` as text, no picture, you can use a temp txt file `systemd-analyze critical-chain > out.txt`

Comment: You can use: `systemd-analyze blame` to show how long each process takes from longest to shortest. This is better than timestamps and you only need to look at the first few lines to see what is taking so long.

Comment: I'm aware of that the screenshot actually contains the full output of the `systemd-analyze critical-chain` i used a picture to show the red lines.

Comment: `systemd-analyze` in general doesn't help that much, I think the problem is related to the last line in `dmesg` output (`[   53.501883] rfkill: input handler disabled`)