# Ubuntu 20.04 slow booting time

Tags: boot, 20.04

i have ssd and booting take still very long in ubuntu 18.04 it doesnt take so long
[image]

Comment: You may make a graphical plot to have the full overview: `systemd-analyze plot > boot_analysis.svg`. You can then view the plot with your image viewer, e.g. `eog boot_analysis.svg`

Comment: @vanadium Here https://ibb.co/8BfysNN

Comment: Information should be added to your question. Use "edit". Perhaps instead you could add add `systemd-analyze critical-chain` which provides similar summary info in text format. Check this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013830/slow-boot-long-kernel-load-time-due-to-wrong-resume-device

Comment: here https://ibb.co/yPhqBBh

Comment: Copy text in terminal and paste in your question (use "edit"). Format as code. It is not useful to add important information to the comments.