# Long boot time, /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume not found

Tags: mount, fstab, mountpoint, boot-time

After I mount a hdd I am finding relatively long boot time on ubuntu 20.04.
On my PCI gen4 nvme, `systemd-analyze`

```
Startup finished in 10.499s (firmware) + 3.259s (loader) + 4.428s (kernel) + 8.384s (userspace) = 26.572s 
graphical.target reached after 8.379s in userspace
```

which sometimes goes above 31s!

My `/etc/fstab` looks like this.

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=db3bac2a-f735-4b0d-a6b4-dc99fdf1a60b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=F40C-278D  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

###/dev/sda1    /work    ext4    defaults    0    1
UUID=531b1b74-891f-4f18-a288-cba9990bd31d /work ext4    defaults    0    0
```

However following [Slow boot, long kernel load time, due to wrong resume device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013830/slow-boot-long-kernel-load-time-due-to-wrong-resume-device/1013935#1013935)
I tried to edit  `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` which I could not find. When I created a file and followed rest of the advices, nothing improved.

I am completely confused to see conflicting information in various forums. Can anyone please help?

**Edit 1:** Random Information: `sudo blkid | grep swap` gave me no output!

`sudo blkid0` gives the following output

```
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="db3bac2a-f735-4b0d-a6b4-dc99fdf1a60b" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="2aaf1779-74a9-4b17-adb2-e212f3627f66"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="F40C-278D" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="9008c0d4-bf69-46d7-8343-1f9429767ca2"
/dev/sda1: UUID="531b1b74-891f-4f18-a288-cba9990bd31d" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="80fb880a-b674-43ed-af6e-c77bd1447040"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
```

Comment: I am using kernel `5.11.16`, but please don't blame the kernel because my laptop on `5.12.rc5` with much slower nvme and cpu boots within 10s.

Comment: I also do not have the resume file. That normally has the UUID of the swap partition. So I assume a swap file which I now have does not create that file. Some settings to reveiw: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187117/slow-boot-boot-19-10-tried-almost-everything & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1018576/what-does-networkmanager-wait-online-service-do & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/800479/ubuntu-16-04-slow-boot-apt-daily-service

Comment: None of them discusses about the missing conf.d/resume file? It's really bad.

Comment: I still think something is wrong with my mounting of hdd or swap.

Comment: Some users with lots of RAM do not have a swap, but one is recommended. You can add either a swap file or a swap partition.

Comment: I have 2GB swap..still not the file.